# How to write a program which runs two tasks independently?

Tags: c

I would like to write a program in which the user guess a number within a specific time period.
If he fails to guess right number within the time period then timeout happens and the game will begin from the first.

Like

```
main() {
    int i, timer;
    while(1) {
        /* How to run the timer independently and it will signal that time out !!!*/
        for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            printf("\n Guess the value of i : ");
            scanf("%d", &j);
            if(i != j) {
                printf("Bad Luck wrong Guess ");
            }
            else
                printf("Great, You guessed correctly \n");
        }
    }
}
```

In this program I am just can not get the idea where to run the timer and how?
Please help me.

Comment: When the timer expires, do you want to interrupt the call to `scanf` or are you happy to wait until the user has finished entering data, and then check the timeout?

Comment: You can use `select()` with a timeout on stdin.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I want the timer will run independently and for loop will run independently when timeout will happen (say 10sec) it will interrupt scanf and will print on the screen that, timeout happened.. Try once again

Comment: @chrisaycock: `select()` basically used for `socket` programming. How to use it for `timeout`?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, did you checked **man socket** before posting the above comment?

Comment: @tuxuday: Sorry to say, but I did not check the man page of socket. But as I know `select()` is mainly used for `socket`. May be I am wrong

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak `select()` is used for *file descriptors*. Sockets and stdin are both file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem appears to be that scanf() does not return until the user has pressed Enter. So even if the timer has expired, nothing can happen until the user presses Enter.

In standard ANSI C, there is no real solution to this. You will need to make use of platform-specific functions.

One possibility on Windows would be to use the conio.h header file with functions like [_kbhit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx). That allows you to test if a key has been pressed before you try to read it, so if no key has been pressed you can go on to check the timer. If a key has been pressed, you can read it with getc() without fear that getc() will just sit there waiting for the user to press a key. Keep adding keys read to a character array until you read a '\n' character. Then use sscanf() to convert the string into a number.

For the timer itself, you could just check the return value from the time() function.

This isn't the most efficient way to solve the problem, because when you write the code you'll find that the program is looping round testing _kbhit() again and again.

A more efficient solution on Windows would be to use overlapped I/O, but this is probably beyond the scope of what you are currently attempting.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `gettimeofday()` and checking the time before each `scanf` if time limit is exceeded you can break the loop and display message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the signal to countdown and trigger the corresponding action.

```
signal(SIGALRM,countdown);
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&new_timeset,NULL);
```

countdown is the function you want to execute